# Useful operations on free arrows

Tags: generics, haskell, arrows

We know free monads are useful, and packages like [Operational](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/operational/) make it easy to define new monads by only caring about the application-specific effects, not the monadic structure itself.

We can easily define "free arrows" analogous to how free monads are defined:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}
module FreeA
       ( FreeA, effect
       ) where

import Prelude hiding ((.), id)
import Control.Category
import Control.Arrow
import Control.Applicative
import Data.Monoid

data FreeA eff a b where
    Pure :: (a -> b) -> FreeA eff a b
    Effect :: eff a b -> FreeA eff a b
    Seq :: FreeA eff a b -> FreeA eff b c -> FreeA eff a c
    Par :: FreeA eff a₁ b₁ -> FreeA eff a₂ b₂ -> FreeA eff (a₁, a₂) (b₁, b₂)

effect :: eff a b -> FreeA eff a b
effect = Effect

instance Category (FreeA eff) where
    id = Pure id
    (.) = flip Seq

instance Arrow (FreeA eff) where
    arr = Pure
    first f = Par f id
    second f = Par id f
    (***) = Par
```

My question is, what would be the most useful generic operations on free arrows? For my particular application, I needed special cases of these two:

```
{-# LANGUAGE Rank2Types #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
analyze :: forall f eff a₀ b₀ r. (Applicative f, Monoid r)
        => (forall a b. eff a b -> f r)
        -> FreeA eff a₀ b₀ -> f r
analyze visit = go
  where
    go :: forall a b. FreeA eff a b -> f r
    go arr = case arr of
        Pure _ -> pure mempty
        Seq f₁ f₂ -> mappend <$> go f₁ <*> go f₂
        Par f₁ f₂ -> mappend <$> go f₁ <*> go f₂
        Effect eff -> visit eff

evalA :: forall eff arr a₀ b₀. (Arrow arr) => (forall a b. eff a b -> arr a b) -> FreeA eff a₀ b₀ -> arr a₀ b₀
evalA exec = go
  where
    go :: forall a b. FreeA eff a b -> arr a b
    go freeA = case freeA of
        Pure f -> arr f
        Seq f₁ f₂ -> go f₂ . go f₁
        Par f₁ f₂ -> go f₁ *** go f₂
        Effect eff -> exec eff
```

but I don't have any theoretical arguments on why these (and not others) would be the useful ones.

Comment: Are you sure that your FreeA is truly free?  That's a genuine question because I don't know the answer.

Comment: I worry that this question might be *too awesome* for StackOverflow. But I'm sure not going to flag it ;)

Comment: May I ask what kind of application you're using this for?

Comment: @SjoerdVisscher: I ended up using applicatives instead of arrows: http://gergo.erdi.hu/blog/2012-12-01-static_analysis_with_applicatives/

Comment: note that `arr id` is just `id`

Comment: @JustinL.: You mean I should set `id` to `id` in the `Category` instance? Yes, that's right.

Comment: Oh, I meant for your definitions of `first` and `second`.

Comment: The Category instance isn't associative is it? You can distinguish (a.b).c from a.(b.c) can't you?

Comment: @sigfpe: but can you distinguish using just `analyze` and `evalA`, and not getting exposed to the representation?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

A free functor is left adjoint to a forgetful functor. For the adjunction you need to have the isomorphism (natural in `x` and `y`):

```
(Free y :~> x) <-> (y :~> Forget x)
```

In what category should this be? The forgetful functor forgets the `Arrow` instance, so it goes from the category of `Arrow` instances to the category of all bifunctors. And the free functor goes the other way, it turns any bifunctor into a free `Arrow` instance.

The haskell type of arrows in the category of bifunctors is:

```
type x :~> y = forall a b. x a b -> y a b
```

It's the same for arrows in the category of `Arrow` instances, but with addition of `Arrow` constraints. Since the forgetful functor only forgets the constraint, we don't need to represent it in Haskell. This turns the above isomorphism into two functions:

```
leftAdjunct :: (FreeA x :~> y) -> x :~> y
rightAdjunct :: Arrow y => (x :~> y) -> FreeA x :~> y
```

`leftAdjunct` should also have an `Arrow y` constraint, but it turns out it is never needed in the implementation. There's actually a very simple implementation in terms of the more useful `unit`:

```
unit :: x :~> FreeA x

leftAdjunct f = f . unit
```

`unit` is your `effect` and `rightAdjunct` is your `evalA`. So you have exactly the functions needed for the adjunction! You'd need to show that `leftAdjunct` and `rightAdjunct` are isomorphic. The easiest way to do that is to prove that `rightAdjunct unit = id`, in your case `evalA effect = id`, which is straightforward.

What about `analyze`? That's `evalA` specialized to the constant arrow, with the resulting `Monoid` constraint specialized to the applicative monoid. I.e.

```
analyze visit = getApp . getConstArr . evalA (ConstArr . Ap . visit)
```

with

```
newtype ConstArr m a b = ConstArr { getConstArr :: m }
```

and `Ap` from [the reducers package](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/reducers/3.0/doc/html/Data-Semigroup-Applicative.html). (Edit: since GHC 8.6 it is also in base in `Data.Monoid`)

*Edit: I almost forgot, FreeA should be a higher order functor! Edit2: Which, on second thought, can also be implemented with `rightAdjunct` and `unit`.*

```
hfmap :: (x :~> y) -> FreeA x :~> FreeA y
hfmap f = evalA (effect . f)
```

By the way: There's another way to define free functors, for which I put a [package on Hackage](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/free-functors) recently. It does not support kind `* -> * -> *` (Edit: it does now!), but the code can be adapted to free arrows:

```
newtype FreeA eff a b = FreeA { runFreeA :: forall arr. Arrow arr => (eff :~> arr) -> arr a b }
evalA f a = runFreeA a f
effect a = FreeA $ \k -> k a

instance Category (FreeA f) where
  id = FreeA $ const id
  FreeA f . FreeA g = FreeA $ \k -> f k . g k

instance Arrow (FreeA f) where
  arr f = FreeA $ const (arr f)
  first (FreeA f) = FreeA $ \k -> first (f k)
  second (FreeA f) = FreeA $ \k -> second (f k)
  FreeA f *** FreeA g = FreeA $ \k -> f k *** g k
  FreeA f &&& FreeA g = FreeA $ \k -> f k &&& g k
```

If you don't need the introspection your `FreeA` offers, this `FreeA` is probably faster.