# Tools to View Haskell Arrows as Graphs

Tags: haskell, graph, arrows

Haskell Arrows are commonly explained as expressing a directed acyclic graph (DAG) of computations. I'm looking for tools or library code that would use this relationship in aid of programming with Arrows.

From Arrow to graph, a tool could help visualize Arrow code. Since the code corresponds to a DAG of computations, a visual representation showing computational nodes and output-to-input edges is natural. A tool could create a graph to be viewed and manipulated with standard graph tools.

Is there Arrow transformer that augments an arbitrary compuatational Arrow class, capturing the structure provided by >>> and *** operations, and making it possible to inspect the computation as a graph of elementary Arrow operations?

From graph to Arrow, suppose there is a DAG whose nodes are Arrow operations. Is there a tool that would construct from this an Arrow which computes the entire DAG?

I've Googled much of what's written about Haskell Arrows without finding such visualization tools. Did I miss something? Perhaps there is not as natural a fit as I expect.

Comment: Still hoping for a response that helps with a "graph to Arrow" tool. I'm beginning to understand that when the elementary Arrows have tuple types, then the graph needs to be more expressive than a simple DAG, in order to identify which output goes to which input.  Is there a name or a theory for such graphs?

Comment: I can't tell exactly what you're asking with regard to "graph to Arrow", but if you have a type that represents a DAG whose nodes are Arrow operations, it sounds like you can just give that type an Arrow instance and be done.

Comment: @Tom: It would be that easy if the DAGs don't do anything fancy with tuple types. I had in mind for example ![graph of 4 nodes with crisscross of 4 arrows](http://pkturner.org/programming/path4700.png). It looks as if when I fill in details of the more expressive graph type that I need, your suggestion is still workable.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A good starting point is to specify your arrow graph using what is known as a "Free `Arrow`".  You can find one implementation of free `Arrow`s [in this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12001350/useful-operations-on-free-arrows).  Think of this as a syntactic representation of your `Arrow` graph.

The nice thing about free `Arrow`s is that they preserve the structure of the graph, which you can then display as a diagram.  After displaying the graph of connections you can then use an interpreter to transform the free `Arrow` to the desired `Arrow`.  One nice property that free `Arrow`s have is that such an interpreter must be unique (up to isomorphism) by definition (that's one of the properties that makes it "free").

Comment: This is a good answer to the "Arrow to graph" part of my question. Looks better than my "Arrow transformer" idea.

Comment: @pkturner I think what you might want is the `Arrows` language extension, which lets you build up an `Arrow` from a bunch of edges.  Basically, any time you write `y <- someArrow -< x` it creates an edge between nodes `x` and `y` where the edge is `someArrow`.  If that is close to what you had in mind I will add it to my answer.

Comment: That's the kind of thing I was looking for. My ![4 nodes with crisscross of 4 arrows](http://pkturner.org/programming/path4700.png) example can be written
       (a1,a0) <- (source -< ())
       (b1,b0) <- (source -< ())
       () <- sink -< (a0,b0)
       () <- sink -< (a1,b1)
BTW where I come from we're calling the elementary Arrow operations nodes, and the connection from output to input edges.