# Arrows, Free Monads and IO

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, arrows, free-monad

Gabriel Gonzalez in his [blog post](http://www.haskellforall.com/2012/07/purify-code-using-free-monads.html) describes a way to purify code using free monads. Let's say we have `FreeMonadIO a`, then we can write different interpreters, for example, one for testing purposes and one for actual IO.

I wonder if something similar could be done for `Arrows`. Something like `FreeArrowIO a b`, which would be a pure representation of a computation with side effects and with an explicit input, which then could be interpreted in different ways (one of them is IO).

I know that I can write something like `FreeArrowIO = Kleisli FreeMonadIO`, but is there a way to skip monad step and define FreeArrowIO directly?

Comment: Something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12001350/477476), maybe?

Comment: @Cactus thanks. I've already read both the question and the answer, but I'm not sure that I fully understand what's going on there. As for the question I'm not quite sure how `eff a b` should look like, my guess is that it is a pure function wrapped in a type constructor, but how should I interpret it then? I mean other than just apply a function? As for the answer it's too theoretical for me, I'm not very good in theory (yet, I hope). Can you please explain it somehow simpler?

Comment: "how should I interpret it then" - isn't that the point? It is completely up to you. If you've got a value of type `forall eff . FreeArrow eff a b` then it was built without any additional assumptions about the underlying structure. This is identical to a value `forall arr . Arrow arr => arr x y` - this is essentially what it means to be a "free" structure. If your `eff` is IO for example, you could represent this as `data IO_Eff a b where PutStr :: IO_Eff String (); GetLine :: IO_Eff () String; ...` - can you see how you would write a function `forall a b . IO_Eff a b -> Kleisli IO a b`?

Comment: @user2407038 thanks. Now I get it. In `Operational` and `Free` monad base functor should wrap some value and (for some unknown reason) I thought that `eff a b` should too and had a hard time trying to understand what value it should be. Now I see how it should be done.