# Is Last a free monoid?

Tags: haskell, functor, category-theory, monoids

The free monoids are often being regarded as "list monoids". Yet, I am interested in other possible structures which might give us **free monoids**.

Firstly, let us go over the definition of **free monoids**. I have never quite understood how is it possible to define a **free monoid** as a structure which abides by monoid laws and nothing else. How do we prove that something abides by no rules but stated above? Or is this just an intuition?

Anyway, we are going to speak functors. If some monoid is **free**, we got it with a **free functor**. It is obvious that a list comes in quite handy here:

```
free :: Set -> Mon
free a = ([a], (++), [])
```

Yet, one might come up with several others. For example, here is one for [`Last`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/src/Data.Monoid.html#Last) of [`Data.Monoid`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Data-Monoid.html):

```
freeLast :: Set -> Mon
freeLast a = (Last a, (<>) :: Last a -> Last a -> Last a, Last Nothing)
```

So, does this functor make `Last` a **free monoid**? More generally, if there is a law-abiding instance for `Monoid (T a)`, is `T` a **free monoid**?

Comment: For all X, there is exactly one free X. In particular, for any set S there is exactly one free monoid over S (and Last S ain't it). ...but this doesn't answer the interesting question, which is "why?", so I won't make it an answer.

Comment: @DanielWagner I really like this question on [free arrows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12001350/useful-operations-on-free-arrows). Yet, the OP and the answerer define different free arrows (the OP's definition allows us to analyze the arrow's structure among other things - it looks like a tree, whereas the answerer's doesn't). Are one of those arrows **NOT** free then?

Comment: In order to prove that something is a free object, we compare it with the definition. More precisely, we show a unique isomorphism between the object in question and the object built according to the definition of the free object. Building from the definition doesn't involve intuition or gut feeling. You take a set of formal terms and group them into equivalence classes according to the laws, and there you have your free object. It is easy to show that `[a]` is uniquely isomorphic to *the* free monoid (i.e. a set of equivalence classes of terms) over `a`. `Last a` is not.

Comment: @ZhiltsoffIgor You didn't quote the actual definition of a free monoid, that seems to be the cause of the confusion.

Comment: @Li-yaoXia the Wikipedia defines it like a list, as far as I get it. My question is more about free functors though.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. can you link some resource where this proof is carried out? Moreover, I replied to Daniel Wagner's comment above. How do those two free arrows work with uniqueness?

Comment: What proof? That `[a]` is isomorphic to the free monoid? That's completely trivial.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. no, I meant that part of uniqueness. I suppose it works the same way as Daniel Wagner’s “Forall X, there is exactly one free X”.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Proof of uniqueness of what? Of the set of the equivalence classes?

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. proof of uniqueness of free X for every X. At least I thought that was what you meant. Were you saying something else? Sorry, my category theory is quite rusty.

Comment: A free object is unique **by definition**. It's a set of equivalence classes of terms. You cannot build two of those because there is a unique set of terms and a unique equivalence relation.

Comment: There is a small error in there somewhere: "up to a unique isomorphsm" the isomorphism in fact doesn't need to be unique.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. I guess I shall see to looking into definitions then :). Anyway, returning to that question about arrows, which of the definitions is actually free?

Comment: You can find another, more categorical definition of a free object here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_object. According to this definition, if there are two free objects F(A) and F'(A), then there is a unique morphism from F to F' and a unique morphism from F'(A) to F(A); since the diagram commutes, it must be an isomorphism.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221596/discussion-between-n-pronouns-m-and-zhiltsoff-igor).

Comment: Anyway, the two definitions of free arrow are probably isomorphic, so either one is free. I don't know enough about arrows to tell for sure.

Comment: @ZhiltsoffIgor The one in the question body is definitely not the free arrow, because it is in the first place not an arrow: it does not satisfy the `arr (f >>> g) = arr f >>> arr g` law required of arrows. I am not sure whether the one in the sole answer is the free arrow; I got lazy once I determined there was not a counterexample to my claim there. =P

Comment: `[a]` isn't actually the free monoid on `a`. The free monoid is `newtype FreeMonoid a = FreeMonoid { interpretMonoid :: Monoid m => (a -> m) -> m }`, and then anything isomorphic (via monoid homomorphisms, which `Last a` definitely doesn't do and which `[a]` doesn't quite manage) to that also counts. This also gives a general recipe for free structures: `newtype FreeSomething a args = FreeSomething { interpretSomething :: Something s => (a ~> s) -> s args }` where `~>` represents the appropriate kind of transformation (operations respecting the operations of `Something`).

Comment: Actually, I'll clarify the above: *lists* over a *set* *do* form the free *monoid* over that *set*, but in Haskell, where we have certain kinds of infinity, `[a]` doesn't quite form the free `Monoid`s over `a`. If you restrict yourself to finite things, then it works again.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here's one way to understand a free monoid: If somebody gives you a value, how much can you deduce about how it was created? Consider an additive monoid of natural numbers. I give you a 7 and ask you how I got it. I could have added 4+3, or 3+4, or 2+5, etc. There are many possibilities. This information was lost. If, on the other hand, I give you a list `[4, 3]`, you know it was created from singletons `[4]` and `[3]`. Except that maybe there was a unit `[]` involved. Maybe it was `[4]<>[3]<>[]` or `[4]<>[]<>[]<>[3]`. But it definitely wasn't `[3]<>[4]`.

With a longer list, `[1, 2, 3]`, you have additional options `([1]<>[2]) <> [3]`, or `[1] <> ([2]<>[3])`, plus all possible insertions of the empty list. So the information you lose follows the unit laws and associativity, but *nothing else*. A free monoid value remembers how it was created, modulo unit laws and associativity.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So, as far as I understand, if we have `a1 <> ... <> a_n`, we shall be able to insert any amount of `mempty`s at any point to get all the equivalent expressions and only them for a **free monoid**. Therefore, `Last` is not **free** as we may insert any wrapped value before the last `Last`. Did I get your answer right?

Answer (score 4):

> Firstly, let us go over the definition of free monoids. I have never quite understood **how is it possible to define a free monoid as a structure which abides by monoid laws and nothing else.** How do we prove that something abides by no rules but stated above? Or is this just an intuition?

Let me illustrate the purpose of free monoids.

If I tell you there is a monoid, with some elements `a`, `b`, `c`, what can you deduce from that?

- We can find more elements of that monoid by writing expressions involving the *generators* `a`, `b`, `c` and the monoid operations `(+)` and `0` (aka. `(<>)` and `mempty`). (cf. Definition 1, in the second half of this answer.)
- We can use the monoid laws to prove that some expressions denote the same element: we can prove equations such as `((a + 0) + b) = (a + b)`. (Definition 2.) In fact, equations we can prove with just that knowledge are equations which hold in any monoid, for any values `a`, `b`, `c`. (Theorem 1.)

What about equations we can't prove from just the monoid laws? For example, we can't prove `(a + b) = (b + a)`. But we can't prove its negation either, `(a + b) /= (b + a)`, if we only know the monoid laws. What does that mean?  It turns out that that equation holds in some monoids (e.g., commutative monoids), but not in others: for example, pick a monoid where `x + y = y` for almost all `x` and `y` (this is the `Last` monoid in Haskell), if we choose distinct `a` and `b`, then `(a + b) /= (b + a)`.

But that was just one example. What can we say in general about equations that we cannot prove from just the monoid laws? The free monoid offers a definitive answer, in fact, a universal counterexample: unprovable equations are false in the free monoid (generated by `a`, `b`, `c`). In other words, we can prove an equation `e = f` using just the monoid laws if and only if it is true in the free monoid (emphasis on "if"). (Theorem 2.) **This corresponds to the intuition that the free monoid "only abides by the monoid laws and nothing else".**

> So, does this functor make Last a free monoid? More generally, if there is a law-abiding instance for Monoid (T a), is T a free monoid?

The `Last` monoid is not free because it makes more equations true than what you can actually prove purely from the monoid laws. See [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63928050/11143763):

```
forall (t :: Type) (x, y :: t).
  Last (Just x) <> Last (Just y) === Last (Just y)
```

---

Here's a sketch of how to formalize the above.

**Definition 1.** The set of *monoidal expressions* generated by (some atomic symbols) `A`, `B`, `C` is defined by the grammar:

```
e ::=
  | A | B | C   -- generators
  | e + e       -- binary operation (<>)
  | 0           -- identity (mempty)
```

Given any "suitable monoid", that is to say, a monoid `(M, (+), 0)` with some chosen elements `a`, `b`, `c` in `M` (which don't have to be distinct), an expression `e` denotes an element `eval e` in `M`.

**Definition 2.** An *equation* is a pair of expressions, written `e ~ f`. The set of *provable equations* is the smallest set of equations ("smallest" when ordered by inclusion) satisfying the following:

1. It includes the monoid laws: `(e + 0) ~ e`, `(0 + e) ~ e`, `((e + f) + g) ~ (e + (f + g))` are provable.
2. It is an equivalence relation (viewing a set of tuples as a relation): for example, for reflexivity, `e ~ e` is provable.
3. It is a congruence relation: if `e ~ f` is provable then `(g + e) ~ (g + f)` and `(e + g) ~ (f + g)` are provable.

(The idea of that definition is that the assertion "`e ~ f` is provable" holds if and only if it can be deduced by "applying" those rules. "Smallest set" is a conventional method to formalize that.)

The definition of "provable equations" may seem arbitrary. Are those the right rules to define "provability"? Why these three rules in particular? Notably, the congruence rule may not be obvious in a first attempt at giving such a definition. This is the point of the following theorems, soundness and completeness. Add a (non-redundant) rule, and we lose soundness. Remove a rule, and we lose completeness.

**Theorem 1.** (Soundness) If `e ~ f` is provable, then `eval e = eval f` in any "suitable monoid" `M`.

**Theorem 2.** (Completeness) If `e ~ f` is not provable, then their denotations differ in `F`, `eval e /= eval f`, where `F` is the free monoid generated by `A`, `B`, `C`.

(Soundness is much easier to prove than completeness. Exercises for the reader.)

This completeness theorem is a characterization of the free monoid: any other monoid `F` which keeps the statement of the theorem true is isomorphic to the free monoid (technically, this requires both completeness and an assumption that the denotation function `eval : Expr -> M` is surjective). That is why we may say "the free monoid" instead of "the monoid of lists"; that practice is most accurate in contexts where the representation does not matter ("up to isomorphism").

In fact, completeness is trivial if you define "the free monoid" as the quotient of monoidal expressions by the equivalence relation "`_ ~ _` is provable". The hard work actually resides in a separate proof, that this monoid is isomorphic to the monoid of lists.

Answer (score 4):

For the sake of example, let's take non-negative Integer numbers, i.e. `0,1,2,...`. How many monoids can we make?

Defining `mempty = 0` and `(<>) = (+)`. You can proof easily that this is a monoid.

Defining `mempty = 1` and `(<>) = (*)`. Again, This is a monoid (Prove it, it is easy)

The two monoids defined above, are called *additive* and *multiplicative* monoids over Natural numbers. They are different in structure, for example, the element `0` in the multiplicative monoid, behaves totally different than any other element in the additive monoid, hence **there is something inner to Natural numbers, that makes this monoids different** (hold this assertion till the next paragraph).

There exists a third monoid we can create, let's call it *concatenation* monoid.

Defining `mempty = no-action` and `(<>) = glue one integer beside the other`.

As an example, `3 <> mempty = 3` and `3 <> 2 = 32`. Notice, that the fact that elements, are natural numbers is not relevant here. If instead of Natural, we take Rationals, or what ever symbols you like, the monoid would be exactly the same thing.(* read foot note) Hence, **there is nothing inner to the underlying set that makes the monoid different to others**. Thats why, the monoid is free because it doesn't depend on arithmetic rules of the Naturals, nor any other rule aside from monoid ones.

And this is the only way to build a monoid freely, not depending on the inner rules of the underlying set. Of course, concatenation is expressed as lists in haskell.

- Note: The only important bit is that they share the same number of elements. For example, the free monoid with 3 elements `a`, `b` and `c` would be any arbitrary concatenation of those three, but you can choose what ever symbol: `1`, `2`, `3` or `α`, `β`, `γ` ... and the monoid would be the very same thing

Comment: It sounds like you’re just describing parametricity. That can’t be the only condition for “freeness”, because `Last a` *also* doesn’t depend on the structure of `a`, but it’s still not the free monoid over `a` (and neither is `First a`, nor `Const () a`).

Answer (score 3):

Here is another law that `Last` satisfies:

```
forall (t :: Type) (x, y :: t).
  Last (Just x) <> Last (Just y) === Last (Just y)
```

Since it satisfies another law, it must not be the free Monoid.

Comment: I suppose this law comes straight from `(<>)`'s for `Last` definition. What is this law called? How are we sure there is no other law `[]` abides by? What is wrong with the `freeLast` functor I wrote down?

Answer (score 0):

The part about the free monoid abiding the monoid laws and nothing else is just an intuition.

The definition of a free monoid is a monoid that satisfies the [Free monoid universal property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_group#Universal_property). This property means the following:

Given a set

`N`

The free monoid over `N`

`(N, ++, [])`

is such that for all monoids over that set

`(N, (+), 0)`

`(N, (*), 1)`

etc.

there must exist functions that convert the free monoid to each of those monoids. In our two examples, these functions would be `fold +` and `fold *` respectively.

The programming intuition is that if you have a bunch of values that you want to be able to process in a number of different ways (sum them, multiply them etc) then the only way to be able to do that is by saving the values in a list, array, or similar data structure.